# Not name a type error C++

Tags: c++

I've looked through other questions on this error but they're not helping me. I'm still new to C++ and I don't know if I'm misunderstanding something, misusing something, or just plain missing something but I can't figure out what and I need some help. My error I'm getting is

> **SpriteImage does not name a type**

**Sprite.cpp**

```
#include "Sprite.h"
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace ColdFusion
{
Sprite::Sprite()
{
    bufferSize = 100;
}

void Sprite::addToBuffer(SpriteImage img)
{
    if(SpriteBuffer->size() == bufferSize)
    {
        bufferSize *= 2;
        SpriteBuffer->resize(bufferSize);
    }
    SpriteBuffer->push_back(img);
}

SpriteImage Sprite::getFromBuffer(int index) //**Here is the error**
{
    return SpriteBuffer[index];
}

void Sprite::removeFromBuffer(int index)
{
    SpriteBuffer->erase(SpriteBuffer.begine()+index);
}

void Sprite::removeFromBuffer(SpriteImage index)
{
    for(int j = 0; j <= SpriteBuffer->size(); j++)
    {
        if(SpriteBuffer[j].name == index.name)
        {
            removeFromBuffer(j);
        }
    }
}

void Sprite::applyToScreen(SpriteImage img, SDL_Surface* destination)
{
    applyImage(img.x, img.y,getImage(img.filepath),destination)
}

SDL_Surface* Sprite::getImage(std::string filepath)
{
    SDL_Surface* optimized = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* loaded = NULL;
    loaded = IMG_Load(filepath.c_str());

    if(loaded != NULL)
    {
        optimized = SDL_DisplayFormat(loaded);
        SDL_FreeSurface(loaded);
        return optimized;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void Sprite::applyImage(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination)
{
    SDL_Rect offset;
    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;
    SDL_BlitSurface(source, NULL, destination, &offset);
}

Sprite::~Sprite()
{

}
}
```

**Sprite.h**

```
#ifndef SPRITE_H
#define SPRITE_H

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace ColdFusion
{
class Sprite
{
    public:
        Sprite();
        ~Sprite();
        typedef struct SpriteImage{
            int x;
            int y;
            std::string name;
            std::string filepath;
        };
        void addToBuffer(SpriteImage img);
        SpriteImage getFromBuffer(int index);
        void removeFromBuffer(int index);
        void removeFromBuffer(SpriteImage index);
        void applyToScreen(SpriteImage img, SDL_Surface* destination);

    protected:
    private:
        int bufferSize;
        std::vector<SpriteImage> SpriteBuffer[100];
        SDL_Surface* image;
        SDL_Surface* getImage(std::string filepath);
        void applyImage(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination);

};
}

#endif
```

Comment: Try `Sprite::SpriteImage`.

Comment: I'm completely guessing because I don't know C++ but since  `SpriteImage` is defined inside `Sprite` doesn't it need to be `Sprite::SpriteImage`

Comment: By the way, you can also remove the `typedef`, it's useless with `struct` and `class` definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SpriteImage` is a nested type and you have to qualify it with the name of its surrounding class to access it, when you are outside of the scope of the containing class. Use `Sprite::SpriteImage`. It also would make sense to take the parameter to `addToBuffer` by `const&` to avoid to many copy constructions. (Probably they end up being optimized away, but it is good practice).

Instead of a raw array, you can also use `std::array` or `boost::array`. On second though: The declaration `std::vector<SpriteImage> SpriteBuffer[100];` probably doesn't declare what you think it does.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the heads up. I'm not to familiar with C++ yet. I think that's declaring a vector of SpriteImages with a size of 100, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Zexanima No, that declares an `array` of `vector<SpriteImage>` with size 100. You only want `vector<SpriteImage>`. `vector` is variable sized and you don't need to specify its size. There is a `reserve` member function if you have an idea how much data you are going to store.

Answer (score 3):

When used as a return type, you're not in the naming space of the class, so you need to qualify `SpriteImage`:

```
Sprite::SpriteImage Sprite::getFromBuffer(int index) //**Here is the error**
{
    return SpriteBuffer[index];
}
```